# How to simulate the roll of 3 or more dice and ask for a sum of 3 or more?

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics, programming

How to simulate the throwing of 3 or more dice and ask for the sum of 3 or more and indicate the number of calves, or more that are produced.
For example if you throw 3 dice, how many cases will add up to 6 and I show them to you

I imagine something like

```
T ={Range[6],Range[6],Range[6]}
```

but 216 are not supposed to be repeated, I don't know how to generalize for any given

Comment: `Tuples[Range[6], 3]`

Comment: `Permutations[Range[6], {3}] // Map[Total]`

Comment: `RandomInteger[{1, 6}, 3]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t = Input["Give Sum"];
Select[Tuples[Range[6], 3], Total[#] == t &]
```

Comment: The OP asked for "3 or more", so I think your `==` should be `>>=`.

Comment: @    Thank you all for your suggestions especially to @m_goldberg, whose suggestion works perfect for me, was easy, I have a lot to learn especially when you put at the end of a line the symbol "&"

Comment: @m_goldberg Teamwork! Thanks.

Comment: Apparently the correct answer was given to me by Anton and m_goldberg edited it , I didn't realize , thanks to both

Answer (score 4):

```
nCows = 3
nCalves = RandomChoice[Range[6], nCows]
Counts[nCalves]
```

**Edit:**

This alternative answer is in response to a comment that reframed the question, so the two answers resond to different understandings of the question.

```
Catenate[Permutations /@ Select[IntegerPartitions[6], 3 == Length@# &]]
```

Comment: @All ,Thank     I think the closest thing is this,                                               Tuples[Range[6], 3] // Map[Total] but I need you to show me the trios that add up to a finished number and the code asks for the expected sum, something like
Enter expected sum N(example 6)
those that comply with the con are k ( 5 example) , and they are these {1,1,4),(1,2,3)....

Comment: @BeTDa I'm not understanding you. Are you asking for `Catenate[Permutations /@ 
  Select[IntegerPartitions[6], 3 == Length@# &]]`?

Comment: ,yes that's the idea , thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just to summarize, @cvgmt has shown how to find all the possible outcomes using 3 dice with 6 sides on each die.

```
ndice = 3;
nsides=6;
outcomes = Tuples[Range[nsides], {ndice}];
```

@Anton has shown how to find those outcomes that have a given total.

We can use `GatherBy` to group all of the outcomes according to their totals.  Then we count the number of outcomes in each group and find the total for each group:

```
g = GatherBy[outcomes, Total];
counts = Length /@ g;
totals = (Total@*First) /@ g;
```

Now we can answer the questions "How many outcomes produce a total of 6?"

```
Pick[counts, totals, 6]    (*  {10}  *)
```

and "What are the outcomes that produce a total of 6?"

```
Pick[g, totals, 6]    

(*  {{{1, 1, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 1}, {2, 1, 3}, 
      {2, 2, 2}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}, {4, 1, 1}}}  *)
```

### Generalization

But what if there are 20 dice or more?  It would be difficult to calculate all the outcomes, group them and count the tuples in each group.  But, we don't need to.  We already know that 20 (six-sided) dice must add up to at least 20 and can't add up to more than 120, so we could generate the `totals` using `Range[ndice, ndice*nsides]`.  For the `counts` array we can use [Integer Sequence A109439](https://oeis.org/A109439), which provides the expression

```
CoefficientList[Series[((1 - x^n)/(1 - x))^3, {x, 1, 3*n}], x]
```

With $n=6$ the integer sequence is the same as the `count` array we get using 3 six-sided dice.  We can generalize that expression in a function like this

```
Clear[numberOfWays]
numberOfWays[total_, ndice_, nsides_] := With[{
    counts = CoefficientList[Series[((1 - x^nsides)/(1 - x))^ndice,
       {x, 1, nsides*ndice}], x]},
   counts[[total - ndice + 1]]] /;
  (0 < ndice <= total <= 
     ndice*nsides) && And @@ (IntegerQ /@ {total, ndice, nsides})
```

This function can answer the question "How many ways do we get a total of 60 using 20 dice having 6 sides each?"  The answer is almost 82 billion ways:

```
numberOfWays[60, 20, 6]   (*  81987009993775  *)
```

That is the number of 20-tuples of the integers 1-6 that add up to 60.

#### Prove It

This code snippet is not a proof, but it demonstrates the claim that `numberOfWays` produces the desired output.

```
Module[{c1, c2, ndice = 3, nsides = 6},
 c1 = Length /@ GatherBy[Tuples[Range[nsides], {ndice}], Total];
 c2 = CoefficientList[
   Series[((1 - x^nsides)/(1 - x))^ndice, {x, 1, nsides*ndice}], x];
 c1 == c2]
```

This module generates all of the outcomes from using the specified dice.  It then calculates array *c1* of the number of ways to obtain each possible total from the outcomes.  It also calculates the array *c2* using the generalization of Integer Sequence A109439.  The comparison yields `True` for all values of *ndice* and *nsides* small enough to obtain results on a not-so-great desktop computer.

In case you have been wondering how many ways to obtain 350 from 100 dice, it is

`numberOfWays[350, 100, 6] // N    (* 1.52371*10^76  *)`